# Count has_many relationships

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have 3 models: Import, Product, Values.
An import has_many products.
A product has_many values.

I want to find the product with the highest values count and the sum of all values for all those products. My current method is very expensive.

```
@import = Import.find(params[:id])
@products = @import.products
@max_product = @products.max_by{|product| product.values.count}
@values_count = @products.sum{|product| product.values.count}
```

How can I make this more efficient ?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use ":counter_cache", it finds the number of belonging objects more efficient.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, counter_cache: true
end
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

Asking for the value of @author.books.size requires making a call to the database to perform a COUNT(*) query. To avoid this call, you can add a counter cache, with this declaration, Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and then return that value in response to the size method.

Reference : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you go with counter cache for this scenario. If you don't regularly update the values of a product, then use counter cache.

You can combine the three `joins, group_by and select(count())` if you want to aggregate results.

If you regularly do update the values, then you can write your own single iteration to find max and sum. To avoid n+1 query issues, use `includes` to make your code work faster.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be something like:

```
@import = Import.join(product: : values).select('import.*, 'sum(product.values.count as values_count').find(params[:id])
@values_count = @import['values_count']

@max_product  = import.products.join(:values).order('values.count desc').first
```